# We should not lose rep when downvoting a community wiki answer

Tags: bug, status-norepro, down-votes, community-wiki

Why do we lose rep when downvoting a community wiki answer?

The user does not gain or lose. Why should we?

For example this answer: [Answer to Post Your Boat Programming Pics!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/114917/155556)

I am proposing **not** losing rep when downvoting a community wiki post.

With that -- I am proposing that in order to downvote a CW post (to prevent uber downvotes on *bad* answers) there should be a bigger amount of rep needed to downvote CW answers.

---

### Update:

Changing this to a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) because I did lose rep for downvoting that answer, but now its mysteriously back.... what happened?

Comment: Pics or it didn't happen :P.  Seriously though, "mysteriously disappearing and reappearing rep" usually means it was something else or nothing and you misread/imagined it.  Happens all the time ;)

Comment: just happened to me on the [boat programming pics answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/114917/133693) too

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> I am proposing **not** losing rep when downvoting a community wiki post.

We don't.

I tried it to confirm. No rep change.

Comment: hmm odd, yea the rep seems to be back for me. must have been some glitch.

Comment: Might be Caching... http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114564/accounts-list-gives-me-free-reputation/114566#114566 ;)

Comment: Changed to a bug report

Comment: Sorry, couldn't resist it :D

Comment: @DaveShaw :-P ha